# How to decode gzip encoded html?

Tags: http, delphi, gzip, indy

I got data from web server:

```
data := '
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Apache

3d5
????????????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????????????
';
```

The size of data is: 3d5 (in hex)
all is stored to TIdBytes variable "data".

How to decode gziped data, change something in it, and encode back and edit the length 3d5 to new.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Transfer-Encoding` response header is set to `chunked`.  That means the server sends the body data in chunks, where each chunk indicates its own size, where a 0-length chunk indicates the end of the data.  The `3d5` refers to the size of the first chunk.  That would be the full size of the HTML only if there is just 1 chunk of data in the response.

`TIdHTTP` internally handles chunked data for you.  If the de-chunked data has been gzip'ped, `TIdHTTP` can decompress it for you if you assign a `TIdZLibCompressorBase`-derived component, such as `TIdCompressorZLib`, to the `TIdHTTP.Compressor` property beforehand.

Comment: So I think the chunk can't be decoded before you get all chunks ?

Comment: If the HTTP data is stored in memory, such as a `String` or `TIdBytes`, you can use `TIdHTTP` to decode it.  Assign a `TIdIOHandlerStream` component to the `TIdHTTP.IOHandler` property, give the IOHandler a `TStream` that reads from the memory (you can use Indy's `TIdMemoryBufferStream` class for that) and a nil `TStream` to write to. Then call any of `TIdHTTP`'s request methods, such as `Get()`, with a bogus URL. The generated HTTP request will be discarded by `TIdIOHandlerStream` and `TIdHTTP` will parse the `TStream` data as-is. You can then do whatever you need to with the decoded data.

Comment: A little example will be appreciated. Dont understand this part "give the IOHandler a TStream that reads from the memory (you can use Indy's TIdMemoryBufferStream class for that) and a nil TStream to write to."

Comment: `TIdIOHandlerStream` has a constructor with `AReceiveStream` and `ASendStream` parameters, and an `OnGetStreams` event with `VReceiveStream` and `VSendStream` parameters.  Either one of those can be used to provide the IOHandler with your data `TStream` as the `ReceiveStream` and `nil` as the `SendStream`.  For the `ReceiveStream`, use a `TIdMemoryBufferStream`, `TMemoryStream`, `TBytesStream`, or whatever other `TStream` type you want to use to hold your HTTP data.

Comment: Like that ?   `ss := TStringStream.Create;
  ss.Write(data[0], Length(data));

  h := TIdIOHandlerStream.Create(Self, ss, nil);
  IdHTTP1.IOHandler := h;
  str := IdHTTP1.Get('http://nothing');`

Comment: found why not working, forgot to set my_stream.Position := 0;

Comment: Yes, that is how to do it. However, you do not need to call `TStringString.Write()`. Pass your `data` to the `TStringStream` constructor instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can decompress a http gzipped body with the `GZDecompressStr()` function of [ZlibExGz](http://www.base2ti.com/?id=delphi.zlib) unit. Just pass the data, exactly how you get it from the http response message, as a parameter and it will return the decompressed data.

```
uses ZlibExGz;

var s:string;

begin
 // read the gzipped data in "s"
 s:=GZDecompressStr(s);
 // now "s" contains uncompressed data
end;
```