# How to decode gzip data?

Tags: delphi, gzip

I have a variable `data` , the type of variable is: `TIdBytes`.

Variable contains some data encoded with gzip.

How to decode this data?

Comment: See Remy's answer **and comment** here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8597492/9842

Comment: No, but I did provide a detailed explanation of what to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delphi: How to decode gzip encoded html?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597009/delphi-how-to-decode-gzip-encoded-html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to decode the data manually, then look at the `DecompressGZipStream()` method of the `TIdCompressorZLib` component, or the `TDecompressionStream` class or `Indy/DecompressStream()` functions in the `IdZLib.pas` unit.

Comment: I already tested them, they not working. And the unit name is IdZLibCompressorBase.pas

Comment: I found the problem why it's not working, i forgot to set: my_stream.Position := 0;

Comment: `TIdCompressorZLib` derives from `TIdZLibCompressorBase`. As its name suggests, `TIdZLibCompressorBase` is a base class, don't use it by itself.